# Array elements to match in regressively using perl script

Tags: perl

My Input file:

```
my $inp = "sample.txt";

#Sample.txt
As the HF exchange `\mathcal{\mathsf{}}` operator adopted 
in, the same HF exchange operator is adopted in without further 
optimization. However, the remaining `\mathbb{\mathbbm{}}`
`\mathbm{\mathbf{}}`, `\mathbf{\mathit{}}`. When compared with those
adopted in the MR hybrid functionals developed by Henderson {\it et al.}
for different `\mathrm{\mathscr{}}`, `\mathsf{\mathfrak{}}`
```

My Array Elements:

```
my @arr = qw(boldsymbol mathbb mathbbm  mathbf mathcal mathbf mathit mathbf mathcal  mathfrak mathit mathrm mathscr mathsf);
```

> My concern is need to check the below pattern:

`\\$arr[0]{$arr[1] ... \\$arr[0]{$arr[2] .... \\$arr[0]{$arr[3] ... \\$arr[0]{$arr[13]`

`...`

`...`

`\\$arr[13]{$arr[0] ... \\$arr[13]{$arr[1] ... \\$arr[13]{$arr[2] ... \\$arr[13]{$arr[13]`

For Example:

`\boldsymbol{\mathbb} and \\boldsymbol{\mathbbm} ...`

`\mathbb{\boldsymbol} and \\mathbb{\mathbbm} ...`

```
#My  Ist attempt
readFileinString($inp,\$inpcnt);

my $i = 1; my $j = 1; my $cls = $#arr;
while($inpcnt=~m/\\$arr[$i]\{\\$arr[$j]/g)
{
    print "LL: $&\n";
    $j += 1;
    if($j == $cls) {  $i++;  }
}

#IInd Attempt

my (@arr1,@arr2) = ();
while(<>)
{
    chomp;
    push(@arr1, $_);
}
my $join1 = join "|", @arr1;
my $join2 = join "|", @arr1;

#print "($join1)\{($join2)";

while($str=~m/($join1)\{($join2)/g)
{
    print "Matched: $&\n";
}


#------------------>Reading a file
sub readFileinString
#------------------>
{
    my $File = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    use File::Basename;
    my $filenames = basename($File);
    open(FILE1, "<$File") or die "\nFailed Reading File: [$File]\n\tReason: $!";
    read(FILE1, $$string, -s $File, 0);
    close(FILE1);
}

__DATA__
\boldsymbol
\mathbb
\mathbbm 
\mathbf
\mathcal
\mathbf
\mathit
\mathbf
\mathcal 
\mathfrak
\mathit
\mathrm
\mathscr 
\mathsf
```

Could you please anyone guide me where I am doing wrong on this coding flow.

Comment: That's latex, isn't it? Have you considered using a parser?

Comment: A simple question that is `array elements need to check `1 of 1 and 1 of 2 and 1 of 3... and so on.  And the last array check is `13 of 1` ... `13 of 13`... in a file contains matching string.

Comment: The regex you're using in the `while` loop looks fine, so the problem is likely down to the values of `$join1` and `$join2` (which should be the same value). If you uncomment the `print` does it show the right values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the list of terms twice, nested. This will result in the [cartesian product](http://p3rl.org/Cartesian_product).

```
use 5.026;
use strictures;
use Data::Munge qw(list2re);
my @markup = qw(boldsymbol mathbb mathbbm  mathbf mathcal mathbf mathit
    mathbf mathcal  mathfrak mathit mathrm mathscr mathsf);

my $BS = '\\'; # a single backslash
my @expressions;
for my $first_term (@markup) {
    for my $second_term (@markup) {
        push @expressions, "$BS${first_term}{$BS$second_term"
    }
}
my $regex = list2re @expressions;

my $input = <<'';
As the HF exchange \mathcal{\mathsf{}} operator adopted 
in, the same HF exchange operator is adopted in without further 
optimization. However, the remaining \mathbb{\mathbbm{}}
\mathbm{\mathbf{}}, \mathbf{\mathit{}}. When compared with those
adopted in the MR hybrid functionals developed by Henderson {\it et al.}
for different \mathrm{\mathscr{}} \mathsf{\mathfrak{}}

my @results = $input =~ m/$regex/gms;
# (
#     '\\mathcal{\\mathsf',
#     '\\mathbb{\\mathbbm',
#     '\\mathbf{\\mathit',
#     '\\mathrm{\\mathscr',
#     '\\mathsf{\\mathfrak'
# )
```